# Performance issues in SharePoint site

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, migration, upgrade

We have a web app that was migrated from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 and then to 2013 using Database attach and restore method.

What we have seen is that the performance is not quite what we expected on SP 2013. We believe that this is due to the junk we carried from 2007 versions.

One of them being BLOB's which comes up with extensive usage of document libraries.

As we had done Database upgrade, the existing content does not use the shredded storage feature of SP 2013.

What would be other features/issues that carry forward from previous versions of SharePoint and persist (at least in existing content) even on the newer environment?

This would help us in cleaning or perform an upgrade using 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of performance issue you are seeing, did you check your 2013 farm, i.e ram usages, database performance, are u using the Cache i.e object cache?

There are many things which can cause the upgrade Performance issue.

- Orphan items /List/ Sites
- Orphan Users and others
- Cache Settings
- Solution / Customization deployed in 2007( not compatibile to 2013)
- List View Threshold may cause this as well
- Database optimizations

I would recoemnd text your 2007 farm and try to clean it as much as you can then migrate it.

As this is 2 version jump then I think using 3rdparty tool will help to leave the junk behind and give you fresh 2013 farm.